# Error in file.exists(writeCSV) : invalid 'file' argument

Tags: r, csv

I am working with an IAC network function, when I run the code,

IACnetwork(wtsfile, inpfile, estr = 0.4, alpha = 0.1, cycles = 100)

I get the error,

"Error in file.exists(writeCSV) : invalid 'file' argument"

I have my working directory set up correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list the packages you are using. Show us what you have stored in each of these variable names. It's hard to debug code we can't run ourselves.

Comment: One natural thing to look for when debugging such an error messege is to look what is the content and type of the variable holding teh filename. Set `browser()` berfore the erronous call and list content with `print(varname)` and type with `class(varname)`. This most likely will provide insight what is wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.